# Software for finding people on video

Tags: windows, video-surveillance

I have a bunch of files from my camera and need to:

1) find all files where there are people

2) get a timestamp where people are present.

Do you know software preferably free, which can do this?

I've tried to google, but the search is full of -  "find video on facebook" and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Camlytics](https://camlytics.com/) app for Windows. It can find people entering the camera sight and analyze video files.
Free trial version can analyze one file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a combination of [Python](https://www.python.org/) & [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) - both are Free, Gratis & Open Source and cross platform.

You can find a good write up and example in the [PyImageSearch People Counter](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/).

[image]

Picture is from the [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/) web site.

Comment: I will play with this, but I am looking for ready solution.

Comment: Are there any updates?