Video organizer with face recognition
I have a lot of video files and need to find people on them.
I'm looking for windows video organizer with face detection on my videos.
Preferably, it should detect people in masks.
It could be photo organizer too, but it should be able to find people on videos.

Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72591/software-for-finding-people-on-video
